# Unity and Random "Index was outside the bounds of the array" exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

We are running web site with around 15.000 realtime user (google analytics) (Around 1000 request/sec (perf counters)).

We have two web server behind load balancer.

Sometimes every day sometimes 1 time in a week one of our web servers stop execute requests and start to response with error and every request is logging following exception:
"System.IndexOutOfRangeException - Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Our environment : IIS 8.5, .Net 4.5.0, Mvc 5.1.0, Unity 3.5 (same state with 3.0), WebActivatorEx 2.0
In IIS, Worker Process 1 and other settings are with defaults.

We could not catch any specific scenario made this error. After App pool recycle everything start with no problem. And before every request respond with error, there is not any error related with it.

There is one question asked in the past with related old Unity version:
https://unity.codeplex.com/discussions/328841
http://unity.codeplex.com/workitem/11791
Could not see anything I can do about it.

Here exception details:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException
Index was outside the bounds of the array.

System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.NamedTypesRegistry.RegisterType(Type t, String name)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityDefaultBehaviorExtension.OnRegisterInstance(Object sender, RegisterInstanceEventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.RegisterInstance(Type t, String name, Object instance, LifetimeManager lifetime)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterInstance[TInterface](IUnityContainer container, TInterface instance, LifetimeManager lifetimeManager)
   at DemoSite.News.Portal.UI.App_Start.UnityConfig.<>c__DisplayClass1.<RegisterTypes>b__0()
   at DemoSite.News.Portal.Core.Controller.BaseController.Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TState](AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate, EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

My configuration is as follows:

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container) 
{ 
    var section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
    container.LoadConfiguration(section); 
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new UnityServiceLocator(container));
}
```

Initialize method as follow:

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    if (requestContext.RouteData.Values["ViewActionId"] != null)
    {
        int viewActionId;
        if (!int.TryParse(requestContext.RouteData.Values["ViewActionId"].ToString(), out viewActionId))
            return;

        var cacheProvider = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ICacheProvider>();
        List<ViewActionClass> viewActionClasses = null;
        string cacheKey = CacheKeyCompute.ComputeCacheKey("ViewActionClass", CacheKeyTypes.DataCache,
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("viewActionId", viewActionId.ToString()));

        _configuration = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IConfiguration>();

        viewActionClasses = 
            cacheProvider.AddOrGetExistingWithLock<List<ViewActionClass>>(cacheKey, () =>
        {
            var viewActionClassBusiness = 
            ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IViewActionClassBusiness>();

            return viewActionClassBusiness.ViewActionClassGetByViewActionId(viewActionId);
        });

        ViewBag.ActionClass = viewActionClasses;
        ViewBag.Configuration = _configuration;
    }
    base.Initialize(requestContext);
}
```

Registration xml for ICacheProvider, IConfiguration and IViewActionClassBusiness

```
<type type="DemoSite.Runtime.Caching.ICacheProvider, DemoSite.Core"
        mapTo="DemoSite.Runtime.Caching.ObjectCacheProvider, DemoSite.Core">
    <lifetime type="containerControlledLifetimeManager" />
  </type>
<type type="DemoSite.Core.Configuration.IConfiguration, DemoSite.Core"
        mapTo="DemoSite.Core.Configuration.ConfigFileConfiguration, DemoSite.Core">
    <lifetime type="containerControlledLifetimeManager" />
  </type>
<type type="DemoSite.News.Business.IViewActionClassBusiness, DemoSite.News.Business"
        mapTo="DemoSite.News.Business.Default.ViewActionClassBusiness, DemoSite.News.Business.Default">
    <lifetime type="perRequestLifetimeManager" />
  </type>
```

Maybe it is related with high traffic.
Is there anyone encounter a problem like that and any solution ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Csn you post the code of the anonymous method `App_Start.UnityConfig.<>c__DisplayClass1.<RegisterTypes>b__0()`? There probably is a `RegisterTypes` method in the `UnityConfig` class. That method contains lambda that calls into `RegisterInstance`.

Comment: We are using same code when you install Unity bootstrapper from nuget:  public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            // NOTE: To load from web.config uncomment the line below. Make sure to add a Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration to the using statements.
            container.LoadConfiguration();

            // TODO: Register your types here
            // container.RegisterType<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
        } --> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/

Comment: Could it be that the source code you are looking at is different than the source code that is running in production? The `App_Start.UnityConfig` contains a anonymous method somewhere that is called, but the `RegisterTypes` method you are showing does not contain a lambda.

Comment: I will check it and will let you know. Other thing is there is a usage warning for ServiceLocator. It is old but there is warning about passing container instance : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2009/05/12/servicelocator-and-unity-be-careful.aspx   and in UnityWebActivator container passed lake that: DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

Comment: It says in example 2: This one is just wrong.  The two instances are not the same object, but two distinct objects.  Since the argument for the SetLocatorProvider() method is a delegate, each call to ServiceLocator.Current executes the delegate again, creating a new Unity container for every call.  This one also has the same side effect as #3.

Comment: I just do not have access source code for now. I have requested it and will write exact code.

Comment: Here is RegisterTypes method (on production):  public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            var section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
            
            container.LoadConfiguration(section);
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new UnityServiceLocator(container));          

        }  There is not the line "ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new UnityServiceLocator(container));   " in samples. And I do not know why our developer put it there. Maybe this line makes the problem.

Comment: UnityServiceLocator > no, it is inside of Unity : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.unityservicelocator(v=pandp.51).aspx , I think there should not be there completely. It was used to set service locator before Mvc 4 but now we have this line on App Start : DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

Comment: @Steven, thank you for your help. We stopped using ServiceLocator for Mvc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I can see from the stack trace you are registering instances in the container during the web request. The `RegisterType` and `RegisterInstance` methods are ***not*** thread-safe in Unity (and this probably holds for most DI libraries in .NET). This explains why this is happening to at random points and under high load.

It is good practice to register your container only at start-up and don't change it later on. With the Dependency Inversion Principle and Dependency Injection pattern in particular you try to centralize the knowledge of how object graphs are wired, but you are decentralizing it again by doing new registrations later on. And even if registration was thread-safe with Unity, it's still very likely that you introduce race conditions by changing registrations during runtime.

*UPDATE*

Your code has the following code that causes the problems:

```
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new UnityServiceLocator(container));
```

This seems very innocent, but in fact it causes both a **concurrency bug** and a **memory leak**.

Because the `new` statement is inside the lambda, it will cause a new `UnityServiceLocator` to be created every time you call `ServiceLocator.Current`. That wouldn't be bad by itself, but the `UnityServiceLocator`'s constructor makes a call to `container.RegisterInstance` to register itself in the container. But as I already said: calling RegisterInstance` is not thread-safe.

But even if it was thread-safe, it still causes a memory leak in your application, since a call to `RegisterInstance` will not replace an existing registration, but appends it to a list of registrations. This means that the list of `UnityServiceLocator` instances in the container will keep growing and will eventually cause the system to crash with an OutOfMemoryException. You are actually lucky that you hit this concurrency bug first, because the OOM bug would be much harder to trace back.

The fix is actually very simple: move the construction of the `UnityServiceLocator` out of the lambda and return that single instance every time:

```
var locator = new UnityServiceLocator(container);
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => locator);
```

The behavior of the `UnityServiceLocator` is a design flaw in my opinion, because since `RegisterInstance` is not thread-safe and the `UnityServiceLocator` has no idea how many times it is created, it should never call `RegisterInstance` from within its constructor -or at least- not without doing a check whether it is safe to register that instance.

Problem however is that removing that call to `RegisterInstance` is a breaking change, but still probably the best solution for the Unity team. Most users will probably not notice the missing `IServiceLocator` registration anyway and if they do, Unity will communicate a clear exception message in that case. Another option would be to let the `UnityServiceLocator` check whether any instances have already been resolved from the container, and in that case throw an InvalidOperationException from within the `UnityServiceLocator`'s constructor.

Comment: There is not anything related registering on every request actually.  And we do not change it later. We are using WebActivatorEx and everything related registration is done on here: [assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(DemoSite.News.Portal.UI.App_Start.UnityWebActivator), "Start")] - Could you tell me which part of the code see that we register type on every request ?

Comment: Ok, when I look at the stack trace again I see that there is "RegisterInstance" but we never call it anywhere. And I am wondering why stack trace is like that.

Comment: @jandark: Stack traces don't lie. Take a look in the `Initialize` method of your `BaseController` class. It calls into Unity.

Comment: The only thing related with Unity inside BaseController Initilaze method is "var cacheProvider = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ICacheProvider>();" Do you thing it can make the problem ?

Comment: I added Initialize method to my question. You will see IConfiguration and IViewActionClassBusiness called in the same way. But I did not specified before because of no difference. The only thing we are using lock with Lazy class in AddOrGetExistingWithLock method. But same approach are used in other places as well. And there is no problem with it. -For the registration code, we are using xml configuration and it is very basic. Like <register type="ILogger" mapTo="FileLogger, UnityExamples.Common" />, for Cache and Configuration class we used ContainerControlledLifetimeManager, other PerRequest

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access unity.config file for now but I will add exact code when I get it.

Comment: Thank you @Steven I will try an wait few days as it happens every few days. I guess just removing line ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new UnityServiceLocator(container)); will solve the problem.